# How to grant user read write permission to another users home directory linux AWS

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, permissions, centos7

I have two users on my server, user1 and ec2-user

I have added user1 to the `ec2-user` group

If I change the permission to 775 on the /home/ec2-user directory as user1 I can write files.

```
find /home/ec2-user/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \
```

However doing the breaks my ppk access with ec2-user

Even if I change the permission back on the /home/ec2-user/.ssh/ directory  to 755 my access is still broken

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've changed the permissions to the .ssh directory.

The permission to the directory should 0700.

Change the permissions:

```
chmod 700 /home/ec2-user/.ssh
```

and that will fix it.  You may also need to change the permissions on /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys to 644:

```
chmod 644 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Reference**

[OpenSSH Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)